# Symfony + JMS Serializer: Deserializing a DateTime value returns current time also

Tags: symfony, datetime, jms-serializer

I have the following annotation for the birthDate field:

```
  /**
    * @Serializer\SerializedName("birthDate")
    * @Serializer\Type("DateTimeImmutable<'Y-m-d'>")
    */
   public $birthDate;
```

In the request, I have

```
{
...
"birthDate": "1988-09-14",
...
}
```

After deserialization I get an object that also contains the current time `1988-09-14 14:32:25`.
Is it possible to change this from annotations? 
I wouldn't want to process the date afterward and set the time to `1988-09-14 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation below. It is not very clear, but it works.

```
/**
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("birthDate")
 * @JMS\Type("DateTimeImmutable<'Y-m-d', '', '|Y-m-d'>")
 */
public $birthDate;
```